# Aligning a flex-end element to both the bottom and the left of its container

Tags: css, flexbox

I’m new to Flexbox and CSS in general. Here, I am trying to align the bottom **Collapse** div to both the bottom and the left side. I have tried `align-self: flex-end;`, but then it puts it on the right at the bottom. I would appreciate any help/ideas to move this to both Bottom and Left?

```css
.content {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 1 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: 1 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.main {
  background: deepskyblue;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
  justify-content: left;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
  justify-content: right;
}

.aside {
  margin: 0.1em;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
}
.inline-icon {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-size: 18px
}

.collapse {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (min-width: 400px) {
  .content {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: left;
  }
  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
  }

  .aside {
    flex-basis: 10%;
  }
  .main    {
    order: 2;
    flex-basis: 80%;
  }
  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .footer  { order: 4; }

  .collapse {
    align-self: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

}

body {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;

}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Template</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">Header</header>
 <div class="content">
     <article class="main">
       <p><b>Main Content</b><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
     </article>
     <aside class="aside aside-1">
       Aside 1
       <div class="collapse">
         <i class="inline-icon material-icons">arrow_back</i> Collapse
       </div>
     </aside>
     <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
 </div>
 <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</body>
```

**Edit:** Please use a `min-width` of 400px. Lower than that this div is correctly hidden. I'm sorry I did not mention this earlier.

Other questions:

- Is there anyway to get the arrow and the **Collapse** text aligned  horizontally
- Why is the aside on the right also left aligned. I have `justify-content:
  right;`?

Comment: What about `align-self: flex-start`? https://jsfiddle.net/rjdo8s3n/2/

Comment: Thank you Michael_B. Unfortunately, this get's it to the top. I want this at the bottom.

Comment: This? https://jsfiddle.net/rjdo8s3n/10/

Comment: Thank you Michael_B. Unfortunately, this get's all content to the bottom. The collapse is still on right though, not on the left as I wanted. I wanted all the content on the top, but the collapse div at the bottom.

Comment: I can't think of anything other than applying `position: relative; left: -40px;` to the element unless you vastly change your layout implementation (css grid, for example). Otherwise... JS

Comment: warmer? https://jsfiddle.net/rjdo8s3n/14/

Comment: btw, I think I understand part of the problem... I've been editing only on a narrow screen size... when I expanded the window, the layout changed entirely... use a narrow screen for my demos...

Comment: Thank you Michael. For some reason the **Aside 1** now moves to the right in your most recent JSFiddle. Yes, someone edited my question and managed to display it here in StackOverflow. I did not know that was possible. If people looked at it here, they would see the narrow screen size. I had to further edit the question to fix this.

Comment: Thank you TylerH. Can this be done with CSS Grid? I would be interested but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Is there any good place to learn this stuff? I'm left with trying all combinations with no idea what would work and what doesn't

Comment: @TylerH When using Flexbox properties properly, this is simple to achieve :)

Comment: @O.O. In my answer I added a link to a Flexbox Guide, and here is one for CSS Grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ ... though today Flexbox still has better browsers support, so I recommend going with that for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is mainly 3 things that needs to be fixed in your code sample:

1. You've been using `left`/`right` for `justify-content`. That value doesn't work for flex items, they use `flex-start`/`flex-end`.
2. You want the content in the left `aside1` to stack vertical, so either add `flex-wrap: wrap` to it, or better, as done in below sample, change the flex direction to `column`
3. For flex `column` item's there is no *justify-self* property that does what `align-self` do for row item's, so to push the `collapse` to the bottom, auto margin will be needed.

---

The above also solved the second of the two extra questions, and for the first, adding `align-items: center` to `collapse` will center the arrow/text vertically.

*As a side note, here is one of the better read how to use Flexbox: [A guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)*

Stack snippet

```css
.content {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 1 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: 1 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.main {
  background: deepskyblue;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.aside-1 {
  flex-direction: column;         /*  added  */
  background: gold;
  justify-content: flex-start;    /*  should be "flex-start" (not "left")  */
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
  justify-content: flex-end;      /*  should be "flex-end" (not "right")  */
}

.aside {
  margin: 0.1em;
  display: flex;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  font-weight: bold;
}
.inline-icon {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-size: 18px
}

.collapse {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (min-width: 400px) {
  .content {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;  /*  should be "flex-start" (not "left")  */
  }
  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
  }

  .aside {
    flex-basis: 10%;
  }
  .main    {
    order: 2;
    flex-basis: 80%;
  }
  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .footer  { order: 4; }

  .collapse {
    /*align-self: flex-end;           control left/right for column direction  */
    margin-top: auto;             /*  added, push to bottom  */
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;           /*  added, vertically center items  */
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

}

body {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;

}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Template</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">Header</header>
 <div class="content">
     <article class="main">
       <p><b>Main Content</b><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
     </article>
     <aside class="aside aside-1">
       Aside 1
       <div class="collapse">
         <i class="inline-icon material-icons">arrow_back</i> Collapse
       </div>
     </aside>
     <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
 </div>
 <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</body>
```

---

And in this sample I both *cleaned up some properties* and made the `aside2` toggle right/left with the media query.

Stack snippet

```css
.content {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 1 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: 1 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.main {
  background: deepskyblue;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.aside-1 {
  flex-direction: column;         /*  added  */
  background: gold;
  /*justify-content: flex-start;      default, not needed  */    }

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
  /*justify-content: flex-start;      default, not needed  */    }

.aside {
  margin: 0.1em;
  display: flex;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  font-weight: bold;
}
.inline-icon {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-size: 18px
}

.collapse {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (min-width: 400px) {
  .content {
    flex-direction: row;
    /*justify-content: flex-start;      default, not needed  */
  }
  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
  }

  .aside {
    flex-basis: 10%;
  }
  .main    {
    order: 2;
    flex-basis: 80%;
  }
  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
    justify-content: flex-end;    /*  added  */
  }
  .footer  { order: 4; }

  .collapse {
    /*align-self: flex-end;           as this control left/right for
                                      "column" direction, I removed it  */
    margin-top: auto;             /*  added, push to bottom  */
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;           /*  added, vertically center items  */
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

}

body {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;

}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Template</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">Header</header>
 <div class="content">
     <article class="main">
       <p><b>Main Content</b><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
     </article>
     <aside class="aside aside-1">
       Aside 1
       <div class="collapse">
         <i class="inline-icon material-icons">arrow_back</i> Collapse
       </div>
     </aside>
     <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
 </div>
 <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, Perfect. Thank you so much. Once you explain it, it seems so obvious. I am from a programming background, and it is difficult for me to wrap my head around CSS.